# Elke und Leo lassen sich das jetzt nicht mehr gefallen

Tags: verb

My question is about the cases in this sentence. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

> Elke und Leo are Nominativ
>
> sich is Dativ
>
> das is Akkusativ

Without *lassen* the sentence would be:

> Elke und Leo gefällt das jetzt nicht mehr.

Comment: These sentences have completely different meanings.

Comment: Ok. I don't care about the meaning. I care about the cases and the grammer.

Comment: It might be helpful to notice that "sich etwas gefallen lassen" is a set phrase meaning "to tolerate something" or "to put up with something". "Elke und Leo lassen sich das jetzt nicht mehr gefallen" would translate to something like "Elke and Leo won't put up with that any more from now on". So it's probably not too useful to remove the "lassen", because it changes the meaning completely.

Comment: Thanks Henning that was quite helpful.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: It is worth to note, that the phrase without negation has a different meaning: *Das lasse ich mir gefallen* means something very similar to *I like that*.

Comment: It *can* mean that. You can also say "Noch lasse ich mir das Gefallen, aber wenn sich nicht bald was ändert, ist es damit vorbei."

Comment: @guidot In my experience, the not negated phrase is usually used very tounge-in-cheek. If you for example see a beer commercial and say "Ein Bier würde ich mir jetzt auch gefallen lassen", it means something along the lines of "I'd put up with a beer right now, too". So instead of saying "I'd sure like a beer" you say "If somebody forced a beer on me, I wouldn't put up _that_ much of a struggle" ;) So this version is even more derived from the literal "gefallen" than the negated "sich etwas nicht gefallen lassen".

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: Just to proof that non-negated *gefallen lassen* also can have a negative meaning: *»Mein jetziger Job ist echt Scheiße. Der Chef schreit dauernd rum, das Büro ist ein winziges finsteres Loch und die Kollegen sind Arschlöcher. Aber **ich lasse mir diesen ganzen Mist gefallen** weil ich nirgendwo sonst in so kurzer Zeit so viel Geld verdienen kann.«*

Answer (score 2):

The phrase [sich etwas gefallen lassen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sich_etwas_gefallen_lassen) is a set phrase and means:

- to put up with something

> Elke und Leo lassen sich das jetzt nicht mehr gefallen.
>   Elke and Leo can no longer put up with that.

The verb *lassen* is a very complicated verb. [Pons](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/lassen?bidir=1) lists 12 different ways to translate it into English. So, always have a closer look at the rest of the sentence when you find this verb.